# Reverse Bitwise Operators

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

Reverse engineering:

Is it possible to write some python code to get the unknown **c** variable value !
Equation: `(((ord(c) << 5) | (ord(c) >> 3)) ^ 111) & 255 = 233`

This was my logic:

1. `ord(c)<<5 = a` this will give us `ord(c) = a >> 5` , then `c = chr(a >> 5)`
2. normally `(ord(c) << 5) | (ord(c) >> 3))` will return  `(ord(c) << 5)`
3. `&` does a "bitwise and", but & is not reversible.

I will be so happy if someone help me, to figure out and solve the equation.
And this is the whole problem  [*pastebin link*](https://pastebin.com/raw/9eW8CcTh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to reverse the equation, but only if the original value <=255.

```
def fwd(c):
    return (((ord(c) << 5) | (ord(c) >> 3)) ^ 111) & 255


def rev(ans):
    i = ans ^ 111   # perform the xor first, then the bit-shifts after
    return ((i << 3) | (i >> 5)) & 255

print(fwd(chr(0xa5)))  # sample byte to test this out with =>219

print(rev(219))  # can we reverse 219 to get back to 0xa5 or 165?

print(rev(233))  # now for the value from the OP
```

Output:

```
219
165
52
```

It seems that the unknown **c** was 52 (or the character '4' in ascii)

Just in case the pastebin link ever goes away, it looks like the OP was trying to reverse engineer a password:

```
secret = [233, 129, 9, 5, 130, 194, 195, 39, 75, 229]
inp = ''.join(chr(rev(s)) for s in secret)
print(inp)
```

Output:

```
4w3SomeB!T
```

Comment: thank you, i really appreciate your help, you made my day.

Comment: Glad to be of service.